# Apache reverse proxy 503 custom page not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, docker

I am running a docker container with exposed port `8001` on my host. The host is reachable from the host with `localhost:8001`. I am also running an Apache server on port `8000`.

My Apache configuration looks like this (edited)

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorDocument 503 /index.html
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8001/

        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to serve custom `503` error page when docker container is down, but I keep getting default error page.

[image]

Error logs from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Sat May 23 18:07:25.126481 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193025681152] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8001 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sat May 23 18:07:25.126524 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193025681152] [client 10.135.178.51:48456] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sat May 23 18:07:25.126577 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193025681152] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8001 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sat May 23 18:07:25.126584 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193025681152] [client 10.135.178.51:48456] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sat May 23 18:07:33.957893 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193017288448] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8001 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sat May 23 18:07:33.957942 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193017288448] [client 10.135.64.171:65456] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sat May 23 18:07:33.958006 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193017288448] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8001 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sat May 23 18:07:33.958013 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8769:tid 140193017288448] [client 10.135.64.171:65456] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
```

When container is running, proxy works well.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error document should be absolute from the document root

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorDocument 503 /index.html
```

You shouldn't need the negating `ProxyPass ... !` directive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but it's still not working, it's still showing default 503 Service Unavailable. I edited my answer with current configuration

Comment: I have edited question to reflect my current configuration

Comment: Please add the corresponding entries from your error log

Comment: So just an update, it works fine with setting `ErrorDocument` to a website url, it only wont work with local file

Comment: It worked after using a specific html and not a default index.html, thanks!